# Generating XmlSchemaSet from XSD file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

The government produce a specification for XML files for transferring data and provide an XSD file. I've successfully used this to create a class (using xsd.exe) to allow me to create XML files confirming to the specification, but now I'm trying to do the reverse and read in XML files for processing. I'd like to validate any incoming files against the XSD and then, if successful, import the data into objects for use in the application. Ideally I'd use XmlSchemaSet and associated classes to do this in-memory with customer supplied XML files.

Most of the examples of schema validation I've read require the XSD file to be loaded from disk at runtime, but as the schema is static I'd like to compile it into the software in a similar way to the class produced using XSD.exe and avoid the disk-reads. Is there a similar tool for producing code which generates a suitable XmlSchemaSet (and corresponding XmlSchema, XmlSchemaElements etc.)? In theory I could do this by hand, but would take days and I'll probably get it wrong somewhere. Plus I don't want to redo it every time the XSD is updated!

Of course I may be missing the obvious and there's a much better way to achieve this. I'm using .NET 6.0.

Comment: XML files should be validated by the people who create the file, not by the users.  A schema is XML format and can be read by any xml library .  It really doesn't make sense to compile the schema into a project since it may change in the future.

Comment: You could just embed the XSD as a huge string literal in the code.  Can't recommend doing this however.  A more conventional thing to do is to make the XSD an embedded resource.  See e.g. [Adding (Embedded Resource) Schema To XmlReaderSettings Instead Of Filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14185087).

Comment: What do you mean by *"generates a suitable XmlSchemaSet"*? I would think creating XmlSchemaSet instances is a very easy task and wouldn't require code generation. Maybe posting some example code of what you want would help clarify the question.

Comment: @jdweng The XML files themselves are generated by other systems and we want to be sure they conform to the standard schema before we try to import them.

Comment: @dbc embedded resources look very promising, I'll give that a go. Thank you!

Comment: Why read the file twice.  Once for checking schema and then importing. Add schema check to XML the file is only import once.  You said "before we try to import them".

Comment: @jdweng good point! Doing as a single pass will be better.

Comment: Deserialization would include validation so perhaps https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator helps.